# How can I use a CSS transition on a transform rotation when removing the rotation with a jQuery Sortable event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

When I apply a class with a rotation and transition set, I get the expected result: an animated application of the rotation. However when I remove that class, it won't animate rotating back to its default.

I've tried setting the transition on the element before the rotation class is added, on the rotation class, and on both. None of these work.

Check it out on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/curtisblackwell/pen/LgwbC/).

## HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

## SCSS

```
body { padding: 20px; }

.block {
  @include transition-duration(2s);
  @include transition-property(
    background,
    box-shadow,
    transform
  );

  background: #eee;
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.grab {
  @include rotate(10deg);
  @include single-box-shadow(#ccc, 0, 1px, 5px, 0);

  background: red
}
```

## jQuery

```
$('.wrap').sortable({
  cursor: 'move',
  revert: true,
  start: function(e, ui) {
    ui.item.addClass('grab');
  },
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    ui.item.removeClass('grab');
  }
});
```

Comment: This isn't possible in a direct manner since the element is appended somewhere else in`dom` once you sort it. This [article](http://css-tricks.com/draggable-elements-push-others-way/) might help with creating a work around